# Best way to track position of backspace event fired on a textbox control in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the position of backspace event fired on a textbox control in java script.

Eg:- I have handled backspace event by keyCode for a text box control in java script but i want to track that in a length of 6 digit on which position it was fired?

Is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

Cursor Position Control Example
http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/

check out cursor.js